# A diagram of a crossover

Tags: crossover, genetic-diagrams

How can one draw a crossover between ABK and aBk where genes A and B follow the Mendel's law of independent assortment and gene K does not i.e. K is linked to B?

Comment: Welcome to BiologySE! Where have you looked for help with this so far? Is this a homework question?

Comment: It's just an exercice that I'm interested in

Comment: Your question is unclear. What kind of a drawing do you want. Moreover, this questions seems to be primarily opinion-based.

Comment: I'm looking for a representation of the genome in a cell

Comment: I am voting to close as unclear mainly because we don't know to what locus is gene `K` not independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking for, but in the following image, allele K (or k) is linked to B while A (or a) and B are independent.

[image: crossover]

Again, this is just a guess because your question seems a bit unclear to me.

Comment: Yes, that was the thing I was looking for

Comment: Oh, upvote and select it as correct then...! ;)